# Multiple websites running in docker containers, how to implement?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, docker

I am running two docker containers, using the following docker-composer script:

```
db:
  image: cofoundry/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_USER=wordpress
    - MYSQL_PASS=wordpress
    - MYSQL_DB=wordpress
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  privileged: true

web:
  image: cofoundry/nginx-phpfpm
  volumes:
    - ../bedrock:/app
  environment:
    - DOCROOT=/app/web
  links:
    - db
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  privileged: true
```

But I can't find anywhere how can I go about running multiple nginx-phpfpm web and mysql containers for different sites, like web_1 - db_1, web_2 - db_2 etc.?

Also I've changed /etc/hosts file to list all the domains needed, using boot2docker ip, but how to run containers for them? I can't run containers on the same ports 80 and 3306.

Please advice,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Imagine network port is the address of some service in system. So, if multiple services have the same address, which one will recieve "mail"? :)
The thing is that only one process can bind to certain network port. 
To resolve your problem with nginx containers you have to configure some frontend proxy (such as haproxy). You need to bind it to :80 port to accept all incoming connections. After that, in haproxy.cfg you define acls and backends. 
For expample:

`acl web1 hdr_beg(Host) www.web1.com
acl web2 hdr_beg(Host) www.some_other_web.com
 ....
use_backend web1_backend if web1
use_backend web2_backend if web2
....
backend web1_backend
...
  server web1_server localhost:<random port of nginx container>
backend web2_backend
...
  server web2_server localhost:<other random port of nginx container>`

So, when the connection comes to :80 port, haproxy parses Host header and proxies connection to matching backend.

With MySQL you can define different bind ports for each instance and configure you php applications to establish connect to needed port. Example:

`web_1 would use db_1 (port 3306)
web_2 would use db_2 (port 3307)`

 and so on